# Eloquent deleting model event doesn't fire

Tags: laravel-4, model, eloquent

I have 2 models defined:

Program model:

```
class Program extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = [];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($program)
        {
            DB::table('descriptions')->where('id',$program->id)->delete();
            return true;

        });
    }

    public function description()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('Description');
    }
}
```

Description model, where description for the program is defined

```
class Description extends \Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function program()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Program','id','id');
    }
}
```

When I delete Program with specific name I want the description for that program to be deleted too.

So:

```
Program::where('name',Input::get('name'))->delete();
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't fire "deleting" event for Program model and the description isn't deleted.

Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is :

```
Program::where('name',Input::get('name'))->first()->delete();
```

Comment: I tried this as per this link: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536 but it still doesn't work for me.